# ASP.Net MVC - Create Custom Routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create a custom routing. Here is what I've tried but does not work, what am I doign wrong?

Expected Call:

```
MyWebsite/Friend/Respond/55/4

routes.MapRoute(
            name : "Friend",
            url : "Friend/Respond/{id}/{state}"
);

// This method is in a Controller Named FriendController
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Respond(int id, int state)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

**ANSWER:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name : "ExtraParameter",
            url : "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{state}",
            defaults : new { }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post an example ActionLink to trigger your route?

Have you set-up defaults for your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Specifically the third argument in MapRoute. You might need to set your id and state parameters as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: Yes I have the default routing and here is the expected link: MyWebsite/Friend/Respond/55/4   There is no ActionLink I'm calling this service from an iOS client

Comment: Have you setup the defaults for your Friends route though? like so... `routes.MapRoute(
    "Friend", 
    "Friend/Respond/{id}/{state}", 
    new { controller = "Friend", action = "Respond", id = UrlParameter.Optional, State = UrlParameter.Optional });`

Comment: Setting parameters as optional was not required, but setting "controller, and "action" was. fixed the issue thanks. I was hoping based on the url it would detect them, but it doesn't

Comment: Actually I didn't have to do that either, Just changed it so that it's not specific to any controller

Answer (score 1):

You can set id and state UrlParameter.Optional.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{state}", 
    new { controller = "yourcontrollername", action = "youraction", id = UrlParameter.Optional, state = UrlParameter.Optional 
    });
```